# Add ORCID after author and affilition's number

Tags: article, author, affiliation, authblk

I need to insert the ORCID logos (which should be hyperlinked to the URLs of the researchers) in author list, but I think it looks cleaner after each author names and affiliation's numbers, as in the image below:
[image: Screenshot of the title and author list of a paper meeting my criteria]

However, I'm not managing to move the ORCID logo from between the author name and the affiliation's number. I'm using the [orcidlink](https://ctan.org/pkg/orcidlink) package from CTAN as below:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% Package for author affiliations
\usepackage{authblk}

% Package for inserting the ORCID logo
\usepackage{orcidlink}

\title{A great title}

\author[1]{John Doe \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0001}}
\author[2]{Jane Doe \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0001}}
\author[3]{John Roe \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0001}}
\author[1]{Jane Roe \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0001}}

\affil[1]{University, City, Country}
\affil[2]{University, City, Country}
\affil[3]{University, City, Country}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

A great paper.

\end{document}
```

Which gives me:
[image: Screenshot of the PDF file after compilation of the code]

As you can see, the ORCID logo is not correctly placed.

How can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to define the authors and affiliations in a slightly other way:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Package for author affiliations
\usepackage{authblk}

% Package for inserting the ORCID logo
\usepackage{orcidlink}

\title{A great title}

\author{
John Doe $^{1}$\orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0001},
Jane Doe $^{2}$\orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0001},
John Roe $^{3}$\orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0001} and
Jane Roe $^{1}$\orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0001}}

\affil{
$^{1}$ University, City, Country \\
$^{2}$ University, City, Country \\
$^{3}$ University, City, Country}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

A great paper.

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: Orcid after Affiliation]

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Do you know `\textsuperscript` to avoid using math font in text context? IMHO you also should avoid the extra space before the superscript.